# How do I make a scheduled MySql query to pick data every top of the hour?

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have one table that has timestamped(DATETIME) values.

Table MyLog:

```
+----------+---------------------+--------+
+
| logNo    | timestamp           | temp   |
|
+----------+---------------------+--------+
+
|        1 | 2016-04-24 15:57:56 |   29.6 |
|
|        2 | 2016-04-24 16:59:24 |   29.7 |
|
|        3 | 2016-04-24 18:01:52 |   29.6 |
|
|        4 | 2016-04-24 18:59:20 |   29.6 |
+----------+---------------------+--------+
```

I have another table (HourLog) that pulls the 'temp' value from 'MyLog' every top of the hour(HH:00:00) with the value that has a 'timestamp' value closest to the 'timestamp' value in HourLog (because the timestamp values can't always be exactly HH:00:00).

HourLog:

```
+----------+---------------------+--------+
+
|logNo      | timestamp          | temp   |
|
+----------+---------------------+--------+
+
|        1 | 2016-04-24 00:00:00 |   29.6 |
|
|        2 | 2016-04-24 01:00:00 |   29.7 |
|
|        3 | 2016-04-24 02:00:00 |   29.6 |
|
|        4 | 2016-04-24 03:00:00 |   29.6 |
|
|        5 | 2016-04-24 04:00:00 |   29.7 |
|
|        6 | 2016-04-24 05:00:00 |   29.8 |
|
|        7 | 2016-04-24 06:00:00 |   30.2 |
|
|        8 | 2016-04-24 07:00:00 |   30.1 |
|
|        9 | 2016-04-24 08:00:00 |   30.1 |
|
|       10 | 2016-04-24 09:00:00 |   30.1 |
|
|       11 | 2016-04-24 10:00:00 |   30.0 |
|
|       12 | 2016-04-24 11:00:00 |   30.1 |
|
|       13 | 2016-04-24 12:00:00 |   30.1 |
|
|       14 | 2016-04-24 13:00:00 |   29.9 |
|
|       15 | 2016-04-24 14:00:00 |   29.8 |
|
|       16 | 2016-04-24 15:00:00 |   29.6 |
|
|       17 | 2016-04-24 16:00:00 |   29.6 |
|
|       18 | 2016-04-24 17:00:00 |   29.7 |
|
|       19 | 2016-04-24 18:00:00 |   29.6 |
|
|       20 | 2016-04-24 19:00:00 |   29.6 |
+----------+---------------------+--------+
```

The query I want to write should be able to look at the timestamp value in MyLog, get the value closest to the current hour and plug the 'temp' value into HourLog with the (HH:00:00) timestamp.

An example:
MyLog

```
+----------+---------------------+--------+
+
| logNo    | timestamp           | temp   |
|
+----------+---------------------+--------+
+
|      101 | 2016-04-24 17:57:56 |   29.6 |
|
|      102 | 2016-04-24 17:59:24 |   29.7 |
|
|      103 | 2016-04-24 18:01:52 |   29.6 |
|
|      104 | 2016-04-24 18:04:20 |   29.6 |
+----------+---------------------+--------+
```

Query selects logNo 102 because its timestamp value is the closest to the top of the hour (18:00:00) and plugs the 'temp' value into HourLog logNo 74

HourLog:

```
+----------+---------------------+--------+
+
| logNo    | timestamp           | temp   |
|
+----------+---------------------+--------+
+
|       71 | 2016-04-24 15:00:00 |   28.6 |
|
|       72 | 2016-04-24 16:00:00 |   28.7 |
|
|       73 | 2016-04-24 17:00:00 |   30.1 |
|
|       74 | 2016-04-24 18:00:00 |   29.6 |
+----------+---------------------+--------+
```

How can I write such a scheduled query in MySQL?

Comment: You could use a cron job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bear with me, but try creating a SQL file like this call it `query.sql`:

```
SET @n = NOW();

INSERT INTO HourLog

SELECT 0, @n, X.temp (
    SELECT 
        TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, timestamp, @n) diff, 
        temp
    FROM MyLog
    ORDER BY diff ASC
    LIMIT 1
) X;
```

Then create a shell script that calls that file (`script.sh`):

```
mysql --login-path=[your login path] [your database] < /path/to/query.sql
```

Then you should be able to call a cron job like this:

```
0 * * * * /path/to/script.sh
```

Comment: TIMESTAMPDIFF(timestamp, @n) diff 
    FROM MyLog
    ORDER BY diff ASC
    LIMIT 1
gets the value with the smallest difference between the latest timestamp in MyLog and the current time timestamp right? 

But what does 
SELECT HOUR(@n) + 1, @n, X.temp ( ..)X; do?

Why the +1?

Comment: From your first table it looked like `HourLog` had the `hour` column. Is it the hour of the day or the primary key?

Comment: Sorry that was an error. It is the primary key, 'LogNo' ... I've corrected the error

Comment: I changed my answer. That line selects the hour and temp values.

Comment: Would it be correct to use INSERT INTO HourLog SELECT 0, DATE_FORMAT(@n,'%Y-%m-%d %HH:00:00'), X.temp(...)X; to ensure the inserted timestamp into HourLog is of the HH:00:00 format ?

Comment: `NOW()` should do the trick [according to the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now). If you want to do it that way, it would work as well. Have you tested the sql query? I don't have access to a running `mysql` server atm.

Comment: I will test it now. Is it better to use a cronjob rather than MySQL event scheduler for this kind of query?

Comment: also, TIMESTAMPDIFF(timestamp, @n) is apparently missing the first argument. Requires HOUR, MINUTE, or SECOND etc i.e.
TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,timestamp, @n)